# Where can I knockout a Brute enemy with an environmental takedown after finishing the game?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

So I've finished *Arkham Knight* (100%), and am now working my way through the AR challenges, some of which are still locked. To unlock *Terminal Velocity*, I have to "knockout a Brute enemy using an Environmental Takedown". Where can I do this? Am I going to have to start a new game? Can I unlock it in New Game+ and come back to my regular game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways I can think of to get a brute with an environmental takedown.

- The easiest way is to do the Predator AR Challenge called Terminal Velocity. It even has a specific star award for envi TD.
- You can do it in New Game+. (If you're planning to do all achievements, you'll do this anyway.)
- There might be special areas throughout the city with an environment location, plus a brute wandering around. (However, I suspect they do not respawn.)
- A few of the DLCs provide endless opportunities for doing this as well.

Comment: You can also do it in the *Gotham Knights* combat AR challenge, although it is pretty tricky getting the rite into one of the corners where it is possible.